# Getting "Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped" on Yuntab K17 tablet

Tags: tablet, system-error

My daughter has a Yuntab K17 tablet with Android OS 5.1, all of a sudden started popping the error message:

> Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped.

This tablet has a place to insert two SIM cards, however, we've never done that. It's strictly used by her for light gaming and watching videos on YouTube. She was watching a YouTube video when the error message first appeared. She hadn't installed anything new on the tablet in several days. As soon as you hit the "OK" button on the error message, it immediately reappears.

I've spent a combined 6 hours wading through countless articles on the web trying to find a solution and have yet to come across one that works:

- I wiped the cache partition
- I've done the factory reset multiple times after backing up all her files on an SD card. I'm assuming doing the factory reset would negate the need to clear caches and data of the various apps (phone, SIM toolkit, etc) which I've seen suggested
- I've turned off auto update timezone, and switched it to 24-hour time format
- I performed the root recovery check (before and after the factory reset) and it said (both times): "Error: found 1 modified files system check FAIL!!"

and done just about every other thing I've seen in multiple articles and help threads. As I said, ABSOLUTELY none of the suggestions I've read have worked.

I'll include the info below in case it is helpful somehow. I am admittedly an extreme novice when it comes to anything other than basic usage of the Android operating systems:

About Tablet info: Android version 5.1
Android security patch level: 2017-03-05
Baseband version: unknown
Kernel version: 3.1.72+ BUILDSERVER@BUILDSERVER6 #1 Tue Jul 11 18 18:04 CST 2017
Build number: k17 vkb0433_20170711 Custom
Build version: vkb0433

Answer (score 0):

First method involves clearing cache of Phone Dialer and Contacts app, then rebooting your tablet. This fixed the problem for me too. If this fails, try the second method which involves flashing the Stock ROM. You can find it through Google using your phone's model number, and you can also see tutorials on YouTube as to how to flash that ROM in your tablet, and XDA Developers gives you best solution.

If none of the method works, send your tablet to your OEM's service center but your tablet should not be rooted when sending to their service center because rooting voids the warranty and the personnel at the service center would be unable to flash or fix the problems.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make some suggestions. I'm currently trying to figure out how to flash the stock rom for this tablet. I'm not having much luck, but I've also not had a lot of time in the past few days to devote to messing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to disable the current Phone app.

I'm supposing here you can handle ADB commands safely. If you have any queries, you can ask, don't end up bricking your device.

1. From the command prompt, type

   ```
   adb shell
   su
   ```

   (not sure if your device is rooted, but it is required. Look up for rooting guides)
2. To confirm the package name, type

   ```
   pm list packages  | grep 'phone'
   ```

   which `package:com.android.phone` should appear
3. To disable it, type

   ```
   pm disable package:com.android.phone
   ```

   If it was a success, type

   ```
   pm list packages d
   ```

   and check if `package:com.android.phone` is listed
4. Reboot your device and install Google's Phone app from your favourite app store.

Let me know if there are any issues.